# Can data added in javascript arrays be accessed later?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to Javascript, is there a way to store data in an array and be able to access it later. Example :

I have created an array

- If I click on my HTML file button (add a question), a function generates a random Id for a question block (like id="13819").
- It is then added to an array of question Id's
- Once the function is done running, does the Id stay in the array once added? Or does the array reset when the function called again?
- If it does reset, how do you make it to not reset?

Comment: Define the array outside of the function, ie a global variable. That way you can push to it within your function, and access it within, and out of.

Comment: so if I add data to the global array, will it be saved throughout the session?

Comment: Do you mean later in the same script, or later after reloading the page or a new page?

Comment: Later in the script

Comment: If the page is reloaded, data added before the reload will not be available unless it is loaded from an external storage.

Comment: All Javascript variables persist within the same load of the script.

Comment: Ok, that answered my question, thanks.

Comment: Related: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500431/218196)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where your variable is created. If it is a top level variable(global) you will be able to add new data during the whole users session. On the other side if that variable is created inside a function it will be erased every time you call that function.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **Yes**

Long answer: **It depends**

It depends on where you created the array. This is known as the scope of the array.

If it is inside the function, the scope of the array is inside the function, so only things inside the function can access the array. Once the function is finished, the array no longer exists.

You can create it in the global scope, i.e. as an attribute of the global `window` object, but you should try as much as possible to limit the scope of your variables, so that you don't pollute the global namespace

Comment: You can also return arrays from functions. Scope applies to variables, not objects.

Comment: @Barmar, "*Scope applies to variables, not objects.*" are you saying that if the array is created inside the function, it will be accessible outside of it? That is without returning the array?

Comment: You have to return the array or assign it to a global variable.[

Comment: or assign it to a property of an object passed in by the caller.